# How to match array keys from separate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two separate arrays - `$array_before` and `$array_after`. **Each array can have an unlimited number of values.** I can output individual values of the array like so:

```
print $array_before->field_things[0]['value']
```

or

```
print $array_after->field_other_things[0]['value']
```

or I can print all of the values in each array separately:

```
foreach($array_before->field_things as $before_stuff)
{
print $before_stuff['value']
}
```

But that give me this:

```
Before Value 0
Before Value 1
Before Value 2
Before Value 3...
--------
After Value 0
After Value 1
After Value 2
After Value 3...
```

What I need to do is out put BOTH array values grouped by thier array keys like this:

```
Before Value 0
After Value 0
-------
Before Value 1
After Value 1
------
Before Value 2
After Value 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `$array_before->field_things` and `$array_after->field_other_things` have the same length after the transformation? Then you can just iterate through the indices into them:

```
for ( $i=0; $i<count($array_before->field_things); $i++ ) {
    print "Before value: ".$array_before->field_things[i]['value']
    print "After value: ".$array_after->field_other_things[i]['value']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single array and it will be much easier. Construct it as:

```
$array->field_things[0]['before']
$array->field_things[0]['after']
```

Then access it as:

```
foreach($array->field_things as $stuff)
{
  print "Before Value: $stuff['before']\n";
  print "Before Value: $stuff['after']\n";  
}
```

Comment: I cant reconstruct the arrays. They are multidimensional and already built. Could I combine the existing arrays?

Comment: There is a function for that in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971901/how-to-merge-multidimensional-arrays-whilst-preserving-all-unique-key-values) If the arrays are the same and fit the model described then @mathematical.coffee's solution may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really get your question,guess what you want is :

```
foreach($array_before->field_things as $key=>$before_stuff)
{
   print $before_stuff['value'];
   print $array_after->field_other_things[$key]['value'];
   print "<br/>-----------------<br/>";
}
```