# PHP Merge 1 Dimensional Array with 2 Dimensional Array on keys and keep all keys unique and values from 2nd Array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

1st Array: One Dimension,
2nd Array: Two Dimension

I want to merge the two arrays by key, keep the keys and the values of the 2nd Array

```
1st Array (
[30] => 30
[28] => 28
[27] => 27
[16] => 16
)

2nd Array (
[27] => Array (
        [person_id] => 27
        [person_name] => Jazz Club
        [person_job] => 10
        [drink_price] => 5
       )

)

Expected result Array (
[30] => 30
[28] => 28
[27] => [27] => Array
       (
        [person_id] => 27
        [person_name] => Jazz Club
        [person_job] => 10
        [drink_price] => 5
       )
[16] => 16
)
```

Comment: do you mean `[27] => [27] => Array
       (
        [person_id] => 27...` or this `[27] => Array
       (
        [person_id] => 27...` please check your question.

Comment: Actually I just found the solution of @Radek here, which works! --> [how to merge multidimensional arrays whilst preserving all unique key/values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971901/how-to-merge-multidimensional-arrays-whilst-preserving-all-unique-key-values)

Comment: @user2119165, that would work but I would say that $newarr = $arr2 + $arr1 is much easier since support for doing this kind of operation is built into PHP itself. Give it a try :)

Answer (score 3):

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

The keys from the first array will be preserved. If an array key exists in both arrays, then the element from the first array will be used and the matching key's element from the second array will be ignored.

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
}
```

Your solution should be:

```
<?
$arr1 = array (
 30=> 30,
 28=> 28,
 27=> 27,
 16=> 16
);

$arr2 = array (
27 => array (
        person_id => 27,
        person_name => "Jazz Club",
        person_job => 10,
        drink_price => 5
       )

);

$newarr = $arr2 + $arr1;

print_r($newarr);
?>
```

Gives the following result

```
Array
(
    [27] => Array
        (
            [person_id] => 27
            [person_name] => Jazz Club
            [person_job] => 10
            [drink_price] => 5
        )

    [30] => 30
    [28] => 28
    [16] => 16
)
```

Comment: would this give the expected output?

Comment: As I understood from what you said that would not give the expected result please check the question.

Comment: Yes I think this is what the OP wants

Comment: so what you say about this? `[27] => [27] => Array
       (`

Comment: I think the text of the question and the code in the question are different. I believe the text in the question speaks for what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by this simple line :

```
$firstArray[27]=$2ndArray;
```

**DEMO [HERE](http://codepad.viper-7.com/O9mD7m)**

**Example :**

```
<?php
$first[14]=14;
$first[16]=16;

$first[17]=17;
$first[21]=21;

$second[27]=Array ('person_id' => 27
        ,'person_name' => 'Jazz Club'
        ,'person_job' => 10
        ,'drink_price' => 5
       );

$first[27]=$second;

echo '<pre>';

print_r($first);
echo '</pre>';
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [14] => 14
    [16] => 16
    [17] => 17
    [21] => 21
    [27] => Array
        (
            [27] => Array
                (
                    [person_id] => 27
                    [person_name] => Jazz Club
                    [person_job] => 10
                    [drink_price] => 5
                )

        )

)
```